# Getting the value null of the variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, httpconnection

Here is my code in this code the value inside the try block I am getting the value of **httpconn = null** but in the first line I am storing the value into the variable **httpconn** in the first line why it so. I am getting **nullpointerexception**.

```
public static String requestToken()
    {
         String url = Const.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL;
         String header = oauth_header(url, HttpProtocolConstants.HTTP_METHOD_GET);
         String requestTokenUrl = concatURL(url, header);
         HttpConnection httpConn = null;
         InputStream input = null;
         try
         {

            httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(requestTokenUrl); // kris connection
             httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpProtocolConstants.HTTP_METHOD_GET);
             httpConn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate","OAuth realm=http://twitter.com/");
             httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

             input = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
             int resp = httpConn.getResponseCode();
             if (resp == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
             {

                 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 int ch;
                 while ( (ch = input.read()) != -1)
                 {
                     buffer.append( (char) ch);
                 }
                 String content = buffer.toString();
                 Const.token = content.substring(content.indexOf((Const.OAUTH_TOKEN+"="))+(Const.OAUTH_TOKEN+"=").length(), content.indexOf('&'));
                 Const.tokenSecret = content.substring(content.indexOf((Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET+"="))+(Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET+"=").length(), content.length());

                 message = httpConn.getResponseMessage();


             }
             return message;//(getTwitterMessage(httpConn.getResponseCode()));
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                return "exception";
            }
            catch (Exception nc) 
            {
                return "noConnection";
            } finally {
             try {
                 httpConn.close();
                 input.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: Perhaps `Connector.open()` is returning `null`?

Comment: then what i should do. Do you have any idea ....

Comment: i am getting the value of **requestTokenUrl** while debugging can you tell me what is going wrong here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `finally` block, do

```
if (httpConn != null)
    httpConn.close();

if (input != null)
    input.close();
```

If e.g. in the code you posted `Connector.open()` throws an exception, `httpConn` will not be initialized to anything other than `null`. You will catch that exception and want to return information related to it but before returning, you try to access a null pointer (in the `finally` block) which raises the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your suggestions it works now.but while running this code i am getting the login page instead of the ALLOW OR DENY page.what it means?is still any thing wrong in my code.

Comment: I can't tell (I don't know the URL you're trying to connect etc.). If it's http (not https), you might want to follow the traffic with something like wireshark, you may get some idea what happens between your program and the servers. Otherwise, I'd suggest that you post a new question with a specific description of what you are trying to do and what problems you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception is thrown when:

> > Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object
> >     is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a
  null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it
  were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of
  null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a
  Throwable value.

So this indicates that your `httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(requestTokenUrl); // kris connection` is not working. Check in that